# How to scroll to a Specific Place only once | Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to make searching in app more comfortable when user tap Searchbox by scrolling page lower because keyboard is covering list. First tap on Searchbox scrolls down page, but it can scroll again if tapped.[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNBFx.png)

[when i tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXvC4.png)
[when i tap again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMYhD.png)

Here is my code:

```
    `class _SearchBox extends StatelessWidget {
final Function()? onReset;
final TextEditingController? controller;
final ScrollController? scrollController;
final FocusNode? focusNode;

const _SearchBox({
Key? key,
this.onReset,
this.controller,
this.scrollController,
this.focusNode,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final InputBorder border =
    OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]!));

return TextField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
  onTap: () {
    scrollController?.animateTo(10 * 1000,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        curve: Curves.bounceIn);
  },
  autofocus: true,
  controller: controller,`
```

I tried using focunNode but didn't get result. I want Scroll work only work one time, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand where the problem is, but I have come up with a solution. You can integrate this code according to your needs.

[demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clzmq.gif)

```dart
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final double textfieldHeight = 80;
  final double itemHeight = 100;

  void _scrollToIndex(int index) {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      index * itemHeight + textfieldHeight, 
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  }
  // index is a value that represents the position of the TextField in your list
  // itemHeight is a value that represents the height of each item in your list
  // note, if the TextField has focus, scrolling to the indices below the TextField will not occur.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: [
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              TextField(
                autofocus: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "TextField",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
                ),
                onTap: () => _scrollToIndex(5)
              ),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
              dummyWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container dummyWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: itemHeight, 
      color: Colors.amber,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    );
  }
```